# Текущие данные из БД в DataGridViewComboboxColumn c#

Tags: c#

Есть таблица d__RenderedServiceBody, в которой имеются внешние ключи к таблицам Продукты и Услуги.
[image: таблицы]

Мне нужно вывести данные из d__RenderedServiceBody, в dataGridView, и заменить столбцы Product_ID, ServiceCost_ID на DataGridViewComboboxColumn.
Код ниже, где я вывожу просто значения из внешних таблиц, но мне нужно вывести значения в combobox, которые выставлены по внешним ключам Product_ID и ServiceCost_ID ?

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        string ID = "select ID from d__RenderedServiceHead where NUM = " + 
        GetStatus;
        DataTable GetIDDT = DbConnection.DBConnect(ID);
        string GetDocument = "exec dbo.GetRenderedServiceBody_v1 " + 
        GetIDDT.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        DataTable GetDocumentDT = DbConnection.DBConnect(GetDocument);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDocumentDT;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        //Продукты
        string GetProduct = "select * from d__Product";
        DataTable GetProductDT = DbConnection.DBConnect(GetProduct);
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ProductComboBox = new 
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ProductComboBox.DataSource = GetProductDT;
        ProductComboBox.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        ProductComboBox.HeaderText = "Продукт";
        ProductComboBox.Name = "ProductComboBox";
        ProductComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        ProductComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
        ProductComboBox.DataPropertyName = "Product_ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ProductComboBox);
        //Услуги
        string GetService = "select * from d__ServiceCost";
        DataTable GetServiceDT = DbConnection.DBConnect(GetService);
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ServiceComboBox = new 
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ServiceComboBox.DataSource = GetServiceDT;
        ServiceComboBox.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        ServiceComboBox.HeaderText = "Услуга";
        ServiceComboBox.Name = "ServiceComboBox";
        ServiceComboBox.DisplayMember = "ServiceName";
        ServiceComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
        ServiceComboBox.DataPropertyName = "ServiceCost_ID";
        ServiceComboBox.DropDownWidth = 300;
        ServiceComboBox.Width = 300;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ServiceComboBox);
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: а чем проблема то? Вы Select не можете написать? Или данные прочитать из БД? Или прочинанные данные на комбобокс натянуть? Где затык?

Comment: например, в главной таблице в поле Product_ID = 26, т.е. Дизель по внешней таблице.
Не могу вытащить выбранное значение в комбобокс, по Product_ID = 26

Comment: что значит `не могу вытащить`? Вы Select не можете написать? Или данные прочитать из БД? Или прочинанные данные на комбобокс натянуть? Где затык?

Comment: Из кода видно, что я подгружаю таблицу d__Product отдельно.
Затык в том, что не могу реализовать связь между таблицами в коде c#.
А именно вывод наименования в комбобокс по ID-шнику. 
Я уже не знаю, как объяснить

Answer (score 0):

при клике на столбец в конкретной строке вам надо делать запрос в базу по ID и заполнять Combobox данными из базы